# Is there a free JSF Webhost out there?

Tags: jsf, hosting, web-hosting

i am looking for a free Webhost for JSF sites..
unfortunately i didn't find any by Google.

It is just for testing .. i know .. i could test it with localhost.
but i do want to have real time conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I'm afraid they aren't free, but they are pretty close.

Have you considered using a cloud computing service. You pay by the hour, typically pennies, that you use and when you don't need the machine instance it can be turned off. You would need to find a server instance that did what you needed or make your own but once done you have one or more machines available on demand that cost nothing when not in use.

Two of the biggest, although there are others, are [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) and [Rack Space Mosso](http://www.mosso.com/)

Mosso for example starts at $0.015 an hour. For a machine with 1GB RAM and 40GB HD it's $0.06 and hour.

Answer (score 2):

Try Google App Engine. As close to free as you'll get.

Here's an [article](http://ctpjava.blogspot.com/2009/04/jboss-seam-on-google-app-engine-first.html) on getting Jboss Seam running on GAE.

Answer (score 1):

Just buy a virtual host and setup whatever you want.  EC2 would work, but you can get a full time server from [linode.com](http://www.linode.com/) starting at just $20 a month or something.  I'm sure there are other options out there.  Running an EC2 instance all month long would cost about $70 for the cheapest option.